# tutorial for HTML canvas's arc function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I can not figure out what all the parameters to the arc() function are (by experimentation) and I have not found any tutorial that seems to explain them. Where would a good explanation of the arc() function be?

Comment: You might get more views (and answers) by adding a "Javascript" tag

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)
```

The first three parameters, x and y and radius, describe a circle, the arc drawn will be part of that circle.
startAngle and endAngle are where along the circle to start and stop drawing.  0 is east, Math.PI/2 is south, Math.PI is west, and Math.PI*3/2 is north.  If anticlockwise is 1 then the direction of the arc is reversed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Arcs

[image: Clockwise]

[image: AntiClockwise]

In the attached diagrams, the only difference is the anticlockwise param. Math.PI/2 always ends south when clockwise or anticlockwise

Comment: Seems like the MDN page is down?

Comment: A newer link for MDN documentation on Context.arc() is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem and made a little interactive page to help make sense of it:

http://www.scienceprimer.com/drawing-circles-javascript-html5-canvas-element

All of the parameters can be adjusted and the resulting arc is rendered in real time. The page also demonstrates how the fill(), stroke() and closePath() methods interact with the arc() method.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes):

```
arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)
```

x, y, and radius are obviously circle parameters.  startAngle and endAngle are in radians, starting east.  anticlockwise is a boolean.

Comment: "This method takes five parameters: x and y are the coordinates of the circle's center. Radius is self explanatory. The startAngle and endAngle parameters define the start and end points of the arc in radians. The starting and closing angle are measured from the x axis. The anticlockwise parameter is a Boolean value which when true draws the arc anticlockwise, otherwise in a clockwise direction." A little clearer than "Obviously circle parameters". :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple example for a brief introduction to canvas and arc function of HTML5: http://pastebin.com/kxB7uJLD

So long.